Access Denied HasRole not calling getAuthorities()
I am trying to restrict path to only ADMINs. Come with it so far, but this is giving me <403 Forbidden> Error:

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Apr 08 01:49:02 EDT 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).

SECURITY CONFIGURATION
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    private final UserService userService;

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/login**", "/error**", "/resource/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")

                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(withDefaults())
                .oauth2Login((userInfo) -> userInfo
                        .userInfoEndpoint((config) -> config.oidcUserService(userService))
                )
                .build();
    }

USER
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity implements Serializable, UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getRoles();
    }

ROLE
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter @Setter
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return name;
    }
}

USER SERVICE
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserService extends OidcUserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Override
    public OidcUser loadUser(OidcUserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        OidcUser oidcUser = super.loadUser(userRequest);
        try {
            return processOidcUser(userRequest, oidcUser);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
        }
    }

    private OidcUser processOidcUser(OidcUserRequest userRequest, OidcUser oidcUser) {
        GoogleUserInfo googleUserInfo = new GoogleUserInfo(oidcUser.getAttributes());

        Optional<UserEntity> userOptional = userRepository.findByUsername(googleUserInfo.getEmail());
        if (userOptional.isEmpty()) {
            UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
            user.setUsername(googleUserInfo.getEmail());
            user.setPassword(googleUserInfo.getName());
            Role role = roleRepository.findByName("ADMIN");
            user.getRoles().add(role);
            userRepository.save(user);
        }
        return oidcUser;
    }
}

I have tried to debug this with accessDeniedHandler, but couldn't figure out the way out.
Also this did not helped:
.requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
.requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
.requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")

Appreciate your help! Any advice is welcome

You need to whitelist /error this is in the first sentence of the spring boot docs under the chapter error management. The error is crystal clear.

@Toerktumlare I wrote this to whitelist /error** :
inline .requestMatchers("/login**", "/error**", "/resource/**").permitAll(),
I don't understand can you explain like to 4yo

I was returning then same oidcUser in processOidcUser. So I created CustomOidcUser for it.
public class CustomOidcUser implements OidcUser {
    private final OidcUser oidcUser;
    private final Set<Role> roles;

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getClaims() {
        return oidcUser.getClaims();
    }

    @Override
    public OidcUserInfo getUserInfo() {
        return oidcUser.getUserInfo();
    }

    @Override
    public OidcIdToken getIdToken() {
        return oidcUser.getIdToken();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getAttributes() {
        return oidcUser.getAttributes();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return roles();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return oidcUser.getFullName();
    }
}

Then changed UserService to return custom oidcUser for loadUser.
public class UserService extends OidcUserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Override
    public OidcUser loadUser(OidcUserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        OidcUser oidcUser = super.loadUser(userRequest);
        try {
            return processOidcUser(oidcUser);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
        }
    }

    private OidcUser processOidcUser(OidcUser oidcUser) {
        GoogleUserInfo googleUserInfo = new GoogleUserInfo(oidcUser.getAttributes());
        Optional<UserEntity> userOptional = userRepository.findByUsername(googleUserInfo.getEmail());
        if (userOptional.isEmpty()) {
            UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
            user.setUsername(googleUserInfo.getEmail());
            user.setPassword(googleUserInfo.getName());
            Role role = roleRepository.findByName("USER");
            user.getRoles().add(role);
            userOptional = Optional.of(userRepository.save(user));
        }
        return new CustomOidcUser(oidcUser, userOptional.get().getRoles());
    }


}

